# Nested pair array in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to use nested pair in kotlin, such as  `"a" to {"b" to "c"}`

I have tried :

```
"teachers" to {"a" to "c"; "c" to "d"}
```

but when I debug this, the data type is:

```
 (teachers, () -> kotlin.Pair<kotlin.String, kotlin.String>)
```

how to use this?

if don't use

```
"a" to mapOf("a" to "b"...)
```

Is it possible？

Answer (score 4):

`{ A -> B }` is an anonymous function whose parameter is `A` and body is `B`.

`{ B }` is a short form of `{ () -> B }`.

In addition,

```
A; B
```

is the same as

```
A
B
```

Therefore `{"a" to "c"; "c" to "d"}` means a function whose parameter list is `()` (zero parameters) and body is

```
Pair("a", "c")
Pair("c", "d")
```

which is equivalent to something like `::noName` with

```
fun noName() {
    Pair("a", "c")
    return Pair("c", "d")
}
```

Anyway, what are the braces in your code? They do not mean "pairs." I think you meant to represent a map (or dictionary) in python, but PAIRS ARE NOT MAPS and vice versa.

Nested pair is something like this: `"a" to ("b" to "c")` which is equivalent to `Pair("a", Pair("b", "c"))`

If you want to make a map in Kotlin, you should use function `mapOf()`.

If you want to make an array of pairs in Kotlin, you can do so like `arrayOf("a" to "b", "c" to "d")`.

Also, arrays are not maps and vice versa.

This is an example of (a pair of (a string) and (an array of (pairs of strings))).

```
"a" to arrayOf("b" to "c", "d" to "e")
```

Comment: `listOf` would be better than `arrayOf` thou